# Responsive Text Overlay on a image

Tags: css, image, text, overlay

I am hoping someone can help me. I have been trying to learn responsive website design using the Skeleton boilerplate framework.

I have used a old PSD template as reference and all has worked pretty well apart from where there is an image banner in the PSD file and over this image banner is some text. If I make the image as a background to the  banner div and add the text within the banner div that works ok until the site hits break points and the background image messes up by only showing part of it etc.

I have spent days trying different things I have Googled and just can't seem to figure it out or get it to work.

Does anyone have any suggestions please I would be really grateful.

My test (learning) website is at [TEST SITE](http://nisites.com/skeleton2/)

Here is a link to a img showing the effect I am trying to achieve (sorry not enough rep to post images)

[[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzmcV.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzmcV.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this putting the image as the `background-image` property, I would also use `background-size: cover` and `background-position: center` as well as `background-repeat: no-repeat` to make sure that the background image always covers the entire div.

Comment: Thanks Josh sorry for the delay in replying I have been sick. Will try this out when I get the chance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position:absolute` . Here is a fiddle with how. http://jsfiddle.net/PB9JD/